# Async/await in NativeScript-vue. Why dialogs won't show in correct order_?

Tags: android, vue.js, async-await, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can I use await sync in nativescript-vue?
Vue code below shows in correct order in browser but, changes dialog order in nativescript.
Does anybody can guess what's wrong in here?

**Working Vue Code**

```
async start() {
      await this.speak("first");
      this.answer = await this.ask("question");
      await this.speak(this.answer);
    },
```

Same code does now show dialogs in correct order while using nativescript.
The confirm() method always shows first.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "starting point",
    answer: " "

  },
  methods: {
    async start() {
      await this.speak("first");
      this.answer = await this.ask("question");
      await this.speak(this.answer);
    },
    speak(incoming) {
      this.message = incoming + " speech";
      alert(incoming);
    },
    ask(incoming) {
      this.answer = prompt(incoming);
      this.message = this.answer + " was the answer ";
      return this.answer;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
  <button @click="start">Start</button>
</div>
```

[image: Edit sync-await-test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because an alert dialog in web browser blocks all other JavaScript code running on main thread. Also `alert(...)` returns void on Web.

In NativeScript `alert(...)` returns a promise which ensures the dialog is closed. When the same code is executed in {N}, it doesn't wait for `alert(...)` dialog to be closed as you are not returning the promise.

```
speak(incoming) {
  this.message = incoming + " speech";
  return alert(incoming);
},
```

Comment: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-texttospeech/ also returns promises